# next/prev function for a circular array

Tags: c++, c++20, circular-list

This is a next/prev function for use in a circular array. What do you think?

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct circular_array
{
  T a_[N];

  template <std::ptrdiff_t I>
  constexpr auto next(T* const p) noexcept
    requires ((1 == I) || (-1 == I))
  {
    if constexpr((N & (N - 1)) && (1 == I))
      return p == &a_[N - 1] ? a_ : p + 1;
    else if constexpr((N & (N - 1)) && (-1 == I))
      return p == a_ ? &a_[N - 1] : p - 1;
    else
      return &a_[(p - a_ + I) & (N - 1)];
  }
};
```

Comment: “`N` is `std::size_t` template parameter.” Of what? This code is incomplete.

Comment: You see the array definition, don't you? Yikes, I have trouble editing. I''ll edit should it be really necessary.

Comment: Looks like just a `next` function; no `prev` function in sight, so the code is incomplete.  Add the missing function, or edit the title & description.

Comment: What about next<-1>()?

Answer (score 1):

## Split it into separate `prev()` and `next()` functions

Is there a reason why you made `next()` a template? If you would only write `next<1>(...)` and `next<-1>(...)` in your code, then just provide non-templated `next()` and `prev()` functions. This simplifies the code as well.

If you do want to keep a templated `next()`, consider giving `I` a default value of 1.

## Consider providing an iterator-like interface instead

One issue with your code is that the caller needs to keep a raw pointer into the circular array. Instead, I would try to provide an iterator, similar to those provided by the STL containers. A simple one could be:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class circular_array
{
  T a_[N];

public:
  class forward_iterator {
    circular_array& array;
    std::size_t i;

  public:
    forward_iterator(circular_array& array): array(array) {}

    T& operator*() {
      return array.a_[i];
    }

    forward_iterator& operator++() {
      ++i;
      if (i == N)
        i = 0;
      return *this;
    }
  };

  forward_iterator begin() {
    return forward_iterator(*this);
  }
};
```

You can expand this with a reverse iterator and/or make it a bidirectional iterator with both `operator++()` and `operator--()` overloads, and you could even consider adding an end iterator that can never be reached. By providing enough of the standard iterator interface, it can then be used like so:

```
circular_array<int, 10> array = {...};

for (auto value: array | std::ranges::view::take(20)) {
    std::cout << value << "\n";
}
```

## Consider making it a view instead

Going even further, instead of starting with a circular array, you might want to have a regular array, vector or other container, fill it using the standard algorithms, and then loop over it in a circular fashion. So consider making a [view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) that circularly loops over a given container. That way, you could write:

```
std::vector<int> array = {...};

for (auto value: array | circular_view() | std::ranges::view::take(20)) {
    std::cout << value << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hey G. Merry and happy everything! I thought a single function template instead of 2 functions would count as positive as this reduces complexity and code copy/pasting IMO and the same approach is followed in the STL (you can supply -1 to `std::next()`). Mostly, I was worried if the next/prev approach is the fastest one available or maybe is even silly, as I see `& (N - 1)` applied mostly to indices.

Comment: There is a conversion pointer -> index -> pointer, maybe I should avoid that?

Comment: In `std::next()`, it's not a template parameter, but a regular parameter, and you can even use it to advance more than one step. But if you do want to follow the STL, consider that there's also `std::prev()`. I would not worry about the pointer->index->pointer conversion, the compiler should be able to optimize it all away, see for example this result on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/jEfWjWcPP).

Comment: that's true in this particular case, but in general, the conversion might need MUL/DIV.

Comment: In the general case, you would just write `i = (i + n) % N`, where `i` is the index to the current value, and `n` the number of steps you want to increment. But since `N` is a constant, the compiler will automatically use AND if it is a power of two, and even if not, it might still be able to avoid MUL and DIV instructions. Given that the common case is just incrementing by one, you could make a `next()` that takes no arguments and has optimized code for advancing by one, and `next(std::ptrdiff_t n)` that takes an arbitrary value but has less optimal code.

Comment: [there](https://godbolt.org/z/6Kq7x6MdT), I managed to get gcc and clang to generate an `IMUL`, maybe the times of the pow2 optimization are over. Even if I used indices, this `IMUL` would be generated IMO.

Comment: What about `prev()`? Can you use % for `prev()`?

Comment: It gets more complicated. Actually, already for `next()`, you want to avoid overflows. You can do that by using modulo for intermediate steps. In general: `i = (i + N + n % N) % N` should work regardless of the sign of `n`, as long as `N` is not more than `INT_MAX / 3` if you deal with `int`s. See also [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707370/clean-efficient-algorithm-for-wrapping-integers-in-c).

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of `(N - 1) - (N - 1 - i + n) % N`. But, after thinking a bit more about this, I think both the times of the indices and the pow2 trick are over. Imagine seeing indices in an iterator implementation. Unthinkable.